I have started doing it and I haven't finished. / I have started doing and I haven't finished
Is it right that we can omit only the second "it" in these examples and the third sentence is incorrect in any case? Is the third sentence incorrect if about that "it" enough piece of information was mentioned in the previous sentence?

I have started doing it and I haven't finished.
I have started doing it and I haven't finished it.
I have started doing and I haven't finished.

P.S. I guess the third example is bad English. We can't write like that.

Yes, you can omit repeated references to the same subject or object. Note that you would usually use "but", not "and".

You could also say "I have started but I haven't finished it" or "I have started but I haven't finished".

"and" vs. "but" depends on what you want to emphasize.

Presenting the text as pairs of sentences combined using and just pointlessly confuses the issue. The valid utterances are 1) I have started doing it, 2) I haven't finished it, and 3) I haven't finished.  The remaining permutation - 4) I have started doing - simply isn't idiomatically valid English, regardless of whether it's presented as a single sentence or part of a compound sentence.

@FumbleFingers That is not accurate. People use and all the time between two phrases. The only thing one can say here is that 3) is not grammatical there.

@Lambie: Nonsense. It's exactly the same question if and is changed to a period in each of the 3 examples presented here.

@FumbleFingers Yes, and 3) would be agrammatical and the others grammatical. 2)  have started doing it.  And I haven't finished [doing it: non-repetition of main verb] or finished it. Same idea of non-repetition of the main verb with or without two sentences.

Omitting "it" from "I have started doing it" can be okay in casual speech when the emphasis is on the auxiliary verb "have" (perhaps because you are contradicting a suggestion that you haven't started) and where "it" is implicit because it has already been mentioned. Contexts where you might do that include when someone questions whether you are doing something, or asks you to do something you already are.
As it depends on context, it isn't possible to review your list of 3 contextless statements and declare them right or wrong, but honestly, they all sound a bit odd for different reasons. I would expect them all to use 'but' rather than 'and' because the second clause presents information that contradicts or contrasts with the expectation set by the first clause. You might also choose to omit the entirety of "doing it" and simply say "I have started but I haven't finished".

Great answer! The shortest correct version is: I have started but haven't finished. Right? But that version sounds more negative than "I have started but I haven't finished." because the emphasis only on the negative verb. Am I right?

@sergei it is all about the context, and spoken emphasis which doesn't come over in writing. At face value, "I have started but haven't finished" could sound like mitigation - reducing the severity of not having done something to completion by saying you have at least made a start. So many different ways to say things, so many different ways to take it.

The first two are not odd at all.

Samples:

I have started doing it and I haven't finished [doing it]
I have started doing it and I haven't finished it. [with it, there is an object.]
I have started doing and I haven't finished. [not idiomatic or grammatical]

The basic idea is that to do something is transitive. The second verb is just using the auxiliary with the present perfect. The it is optional.
Whenever you have a transitive verb you do not have to repeat the main verb and can use the auxiliary without the direct object. The second verb is using the auxiliary and doesn't require the direct object.

He left the job but I didn't. [didn't leave the job.
He has left the job but I haven't. [left the job]
I started doing it but he hasn't. [started doing it]
I have started doing it and I haven't finished [doing it].
We'll be getting off the train in London but you won't. [be getting off the train]

The two first samples sentences are examples of this, where the auxiliary is have. In the case of the present perfect, you do have to use the auxiliary plus the past participle. The object is optional.

He has finished cleaning the apartment but I haven't finished. [cleaning the apartment]
OR
He has played tennnis but I haven't started. [playing tennis]
He has spouted nonsense for years but they haven't. [auxiliary]
He has spouted nonsense for years but they haven't done that. [with object]

[Please note: I am not dealing with the verb to be  here]

Disregard the downvoters.
